# In a python pandas DataFrame, how do you shift row indexes up to fill empty rows?

Tags: python, pandas, row, dataframe

See title.  Basically, how do you turn a dataframe that looks like A into one that looks like B:

A:

```
Index: Field:
01     a
02     b
03     c
05     d
06     e
08     f
```

B:

```
Index: Field:
01     a
02     b
03     c
04     d
05     e
06     f
```

So I want to preserve the data, but shift the indexes together. (specifically, I have this data, and I want to plot it with matplotlib, but I don't want there to be giant spaces in the data, so I want the data points to be pushed together.  Is this the right way of doing this?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just use `reset_index()`:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
  Field
1     a
2     b
3     c
5     d
6     e
8     f

[6 rows x 1 columns]

In [8]: df.reset_index(drop=True)
Out[8]: 
  Field
0     a
1     b
2     c
3     d
4     e
5     f

[6 rows x 1 columns]
```

The `drop=True` says not to try to insert the original index into the DataFrame.

Alternatively, you could try the `use_index=False` option in `df.plot()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  This completely answered my question.  The additional method is also helpful.